# C++ inheritance and abstract function implementation

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual, abstract

I'm getting the `cannot instantiate abstract class` error. Now I am aware of the implications of this, however I don't see how I've done my code wrong. So here I am, asking for help.

I have

`Action.h`:

```
#ifndef ACTION_H
#define ACTION_H

// ===== Dependencies ===== //
#include ...
... 

// ===== Classes ===== //
class Action
{
public:
    Action();

    void set(...);

    virtual void doAction() = 0;
};

#endif
```

`MoveAction.h`:

```
#ifndef MOVE_ACTION_H
#define MOVE_ACTION_H

// ===== Dependencies ===== //
#include ...
...

// ===== Classes ===== //
class MoveAction : public Action
{
public:
    MoveAction(...); // Constructor 

    using Action::set;

    void doAction(); // Do action

private:
    ...
};

#endif
```

`MoveAction.cpp`:

```
#include "MoveAction.h"

MoveAction::MoveAction(...) : Action() {
    ...
}

/* Do action */
void MoveAction::doAction() {
    ...
    setTile(...);
}
```

So essentially I am implementing `doAction()` in the class `MoveAction.h` that inherits `Action.h`. However, when I do the following:

`Actor.cpp`:

```
...
vector<Action> Actor::getActions(...) {
    vector<Action> actions = vector<Action>();

    actions.push_back(MoveAction(...));
    ...

    return actions;
}
```

I use a vector of `Action` so then future Action types (e.g. `AttackAction`) can be added to this vector and all I would need to do is call `action.doAction()` for it to perform the action. However doing the above gives me the `cannot instantiate abstract class` error..

If I change the code to:

```
...
vector<MoveAction> Actor::getActions(...) {
    vector<MoveAction> actions = vector<MoveAction>();

    actions.push_back(MoveAction(...));
    ...

    return actions;
}
```

It works fine (notice the change of all types to `MoveAction`), this would obviously stop any extensibility options however.

Anyone have any ideas? I feel like I'm missing something very obvious.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot have a vector of objects of type `Action`, i.e:

```
vector<Action>
```

because abstract class cannot have instances. You can however have a vector of pointers to abstract class.

```
vector<Action*>
```

This way the polymorphic behavior will be preserved. Note: storing `Action` instead of `Action*` would have been an error even if it was not the compilation error because you would face a *slicing* [then](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing). Remember also to handle correctly memory management when dealing with raw pointers. You can use some kind of [*handle*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) to pointer that will ease memory problems: [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr), [boost::shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) or similar. This way you will introduce a little, little efficiency overhead but this is strongly advised as long as you are a beginner. Do not worry about this because this will probably be the preoptimization. First you need a correct, working code that is not leaking memory, then you can always adjust (optimize) later.

C++ Standard n3337 **§** 10.4/1 Abstract classes

> The abstract class mechanism supports the notion of a general concept,
>   such as a shape, of which only more concrete variants, such as circle
>   and square, can actually be used. An abstract class can also be used
>   to define an interface for which derived classes provide a variety of
>   implementations.

C++ Standard n3337 **§** 10.4/2

> An abstract class is a class that can be used only as a base class of
>   some other class; **no objects of an abstract class can be created**
>   except as subobjects of a class derived from it. A class is abstract
>   if it has at least one pure virtual function. [ Note: Such a function
>   might be inherited: see below. — end note ] A virtual function is
>   specified pure by using a pure-specifier (9.2) in the function
>   declaration in the class definition. (...)

Comment: did you mean: storing "Action" instead of "Action*"?

Comment: Or `Action` instead of `MoveAction` ;)

Comment: @Mr_Hic-up storing Action instead of Action* would be an error even if it could be compiled

Comment: AH! That was it, definitely missed the obvious here. Thanks buddy!

Comment: @Ubobo I am at your service, sir

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Action>>` instead of `std:vector<Action>`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Action {
 public:
  typedef std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Action>> Ptrs;
  Action() { }
  virtual void doAction() = 0;
};

class MoveAction : public Action {
 public:
  MoveAction() { }
  void doAction() { std::cout << "MoveAction::doAction" << std::endl;}
};

class Actor {
 public:
  Action::Ptrs getActions();
};

Action::Ptrs
Actor::getActions() {
  Action::Ptrs actions;
  actions.emplace_back(new MoveAction());
  return actions;
}

int main() {
  Actor actor;
  Action::Ptrs actions = actor.getActions();
  actions.back()->doAction();
}
```